# I need some Math help rotating multiple images towards a point in JS

Tags: javascript, html, math, rotation, html5-canvas

Here's my full [Js Fiddle progress](https://jsfiddle.net/b90mbrkg/6/)

```
function drawPetals(num){
for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
    var p = Math.random()
    var x = bud.x + (bud.size+50) * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * p);
    var y = bud.y + (bud.size+50) * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * p);
    petals[i] = new Petal();
    petals[i].draw(x,y, Math.atan2(bud.x*x,bud.y*y) //Math.atan needs to change);
}
```

}

I tried Math.atan2() but i dont even know what it does and how it works
petals[i].draw() takes 3 parameters x,y and rotation, the rotation is what i need filled in.., it needs to be pointed at the dot for however many petals i am randomly placing around it.

I basically want the petals facing the red dot, creating a flower.
The goal of my little program would be to have a random amount of flower petals, and clicking a button would take one away, like the "he loves me, he loves me not"- thing that girls do.

I'm not good enough at math to figure this out, don't finish the program completely though, i do this for learning purpose, as i am (quite obviously) a beginner. :)

Feel free to teach me the math behind it, i like to get smarter.

Thanks in advance for your wisdom ;)

Answer (score 0):

There were a few problems getting your code to compile. Check the javascript console to find any javascript error. I've added an init method to the bud object. Once it compiled you were not far off.

Use `one.draw(bud.x,bud.y,120);` to draw and `ctx.drawImage(image, -(w/2), -h,w,h);` positioned things in the right place.

A full working example is:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

var TO_RADIANS = Math.PI/180; 

var bud = {
    size:15,
    init : function() {
        this.x = (canvas.width-this.size)/2;
        this.y = (canvas.height-this.size)/2;
    },
    draw: function(){
        console.log("bud,draw",this.x,this.y,this.size);
        drawCircle(this.x,this.y,this.size);
    }
}

function Petal(){
    this.w = bud.size*3.5;
    this.h = bud.size*3.5;
    this.img = new Image();
    this.img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/BMeZIvV.jpg";
    this.draw = function(middleX,middleY,angle){
      drawRotatedImage(this.img,middleX,middleY,this.w,this.h,angle);
    }
}

bud.init();
var one = new Petal();
one.draw(bud.x,bud.y,120);
one.draw(bud.x,bud.y,-120);
one.draw(bud.x,bud.y,0);
bud.draw();

function drawCircle(x,y,size){
    ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,size,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
}

function drawRotatedImage(image, x, y, w, h, angle) { 
 console.log("drawRotatedImage",x,y,w,h,angle);
    // save the current co-ordinate system 
    // before we screw with it
    ctx.save(); 

    // move to the middle of where we want to draw our image
    ctx.translate(x, y);

    // rotate around that point, converting our 
    // angle from degrees to radians 
    ctx.rotate(angle * TO_RADIANS);

    // draw it up and to the left by half the width
    // and height of the image 
    ctx.drawImage(image, -(w/2), -h,w,h);

    // and restore the co-ords to how they were when we began
    ctx.restore(); 
}
```

Comment: Your code only showed a green circle with no petals. I sent you an outdated link btw. I don't know how but i was on the sixth version of that fiddle and not the third. The code in my post wasn't in the example either.

Here's the new link: https://jsfiddle.net/b90mbrkg/6/

Comment: Math.atan2(bud.x- x, -(bud.y- y) )*(180/Math.PI)) this is the formula i needed.

Comment: I think there is a problem with delayed loading of images. You need to run the program twice to get the image to load. Try using `img.addEventListener("load", function() {}`. There is also a problem with mixed content with http and https. If you are clever with the transformation you don't need the atan2 part. My code specifies the center of the bud and then draws the petal relative to this center. After translation and rotation the origin is at the center of the bud. By having the image at `ctx.drawImage(image, -(w/2), -h,w,h);` this places the tip of the petal at the center of the bud.

Comment: I had to click a few times to get the images to load, your example is splendid, thank you, for drawing a random amount of petals, wouldn't it be easier with atan2?

Comment: The way its called with `one.draw(bud.x,bud.y,120);` where you just use the center and the angle  should be easy to adapt for any angle. You could add another argument for the distance from the center to the base of petal, and possibly one for the width, which you might want to change to fit more leaves in.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! :)

This is the formula i needed to make every petal face the bud like a flower:
`Math.atan2(bud.x- x, -(bud.y- y) )*(180/Math.PI)`

For other projects that would be:

> var rotation = Math.atan2( **tx** - **x**
>   ,-(**ty**-**y**))*(180/Math.PI)
>   **tx**, **ty** = your target x and y;
>   **x**,**y** = the object you want to rotate towards a target

As in,

```
function drawPetals(num){
  for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
    var p = Math.random()
    var x = bud.x + (bud.size+50) * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * p);
    var y = bud.y + (bud.size+50) * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * p);
    petals[i] = new Petal();
    //rotation parameter
    petals[i].draw(x,y,Math.atan2(bud.x- x, -(bud.y- y) )*(180/Math.PI));
  }
}
```

I also needed to change the draw function to draw the angle + 180 to get the opposite rotation,

```
function Petal(){
  this.w = bud.size*3.5;
  this.h = bud.size*3.5;
  this.img = new Image();
  this.draw = function(middleX,middleY,angle){
    this.img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/RpYoutg.png";
    // +180
    drawRotatedImage(this.img,middleX,middleY,this.w,this.h,angle+180);
  }
}
```

This is the updated jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/b90mbrkg/7/